# many checkboxes stored together into single string Entity field

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig, formbuilder

What might be the most concise, OR the most built-in PHP Symfony 2.6 way to store a potentially varying set of preferences as a single string on the backend?

I am considering using **json_encode()** and **json_decode()**

from

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

(in favor over my earlier use of **implode()** and **explode()** or similar ways to convert Array <==> String).

On the back end, in SQL and my entity's field *$prefs*, in case of using JSON which is probably a wise format choice, I prefer to store:

```
$prefs = "{"Notif_Alert":"1","Notif_Email":"1","Notif_SMS":"0"}"
```

// not %100 sure how TRUE/FALSE would actually get stored above.  Maybe empty string '', maybe null, maybe blank or missing. Any is fine, as long as consistent.

While in the PHP where I handle most of the backend logic, I want read/write access to this native array structure:

```
 $prefsA = [
            "Notif_Alert" => TRUE,
            "Notif_Email" => TRUE,
            "Notif_SMS" => FALSE,
            ];
```

(I will implement such that reading a missing preference will simply default to FALSE.  Again, the list of preferences will vary per user.  For the sake of this question, let's say all values may only be boolean, though in practice that will not always be the case, and I would use FormBuilderInterface to specially handle my known int and string HTML inputs).

However, everything I've researched in the docs, eg.

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html
- http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceListInterface.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html
- http://sf.khepin.com/2011/08/finally-through-symfony2-forms-and-collectiontype-make-it-dynamic/

seems to indicate support mainly for storing each such setting as it's own entity field, OR as a Collection (and therefore likely as a OneToMany mapping that causes the ORM to create a joined table if I want persistence, etc.).  Neither of these suit me.

Specifically, how can I rely on

*Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder*  to do most of the work (perhaps in *EntityType.php*) :

```
$builder->add('prefs', ...? , [ ...? ] )
```

so I don't have to futz too much with the encoding and decoding in the Controller (i.e. *EntityController.php*), and only as little as necessary in the getters and setters in the *Entity.php* Model ?

My *editPrefs.html.twig* View for now has:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Later I may break it down into widgets, for the front-end coders' sake.

Comment: You should use the doctrine type "array" on your field, so it will automatically store your field as a string in database, and transform it as an array when you use it in your code.

Comment: More specifically, you're saying make the field a new `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` in the `__contruct()` of the Entity.php?  While keeping `@ORM\Column(type="text", ` ?

Comment: No, you should use @ORM\Column(type="array") on your property.